# OpenVPN only works on cli

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have a openvpn config file that with certificate and works with user auth to connect a VPN.

If ir run

```
openvpn --config myvpn.confg
```

I can connect with success. But if I import this file to create a new VPN in ubuntu network-manager I can't connect to the VPN.

In cli I only need to pass user and password, but in the network manager I'm also asked for a certificate password.

```
#myvpn.confg    
dev tun
persist-tun
persist-key
cipher AES-256-CBC
ncp-disable
auth SHA256
tls-client
client
resolv-retry infinite
remote XXX.YY.ZZZ.WWW 77XX udp
verify-x509-name "ServerOpenVPN" name
auth-user-pass
pkcs12 ClientVPN.p12
tls-auth ClientVPN-tls.key 1
remote-cert-tls server
compress
```

Comment: OpenVPN using CLI is different than when using NM. Don't exactly know why, but it is. More than likely it's a problem with your .config file, or your certs. Where did you get the .config/certs files from?

Comment: @heynnema From the network admin.

Comment: I'd go back to your network admin and discuss your problem.